# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'session')

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, electron

I'm trying to set up some cookies for my electron application but when the code on the function below executes, this error comes out `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'session')`.

```
const { session } = require("electron")    

function updatePatient(id) {
    session.defaultSession.cookies.set({url: './', name: 'patientId', value: id})
    ipcRenderer.send('updatePatientWindow')
}  

updatePatient(id)
```

I also tried to use

```
const { electron } = require('electron')
electron.session.defaultSession.cookies.set({url: './', name: 'patientId', value: id})
```

but that doesn't work either

Edit:

Seems like `session` works only on the main process. A workaround is to use `ipcRenderer` there to set and read cookies.

Comment: I followed documentation instructions https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/cookies

Comment: @EmelCD What difference would that make? The error says that `session` is undefined.

Comment: I can import other dependecies, ipcRender (which i used on the code I posted) works just fine and i did use the right command. I'm quite sure it is an import problem but i can't figure out a way to fix it.

Comment: It is difficult to figure out with this. Maybe try ES6 import ?

Comment: I tried, it gives me this error ```SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module```

Comment: If I try doing something like `node test.js`I get the same as you. Maybe running with `electron .` does not throw errors.

Comment: @MatteoVioletto I just copy your snippet, only works with CommonJS import.

Comment: @EmelCD I use ```electron  .``` by default and it doesn't work with ```node main.js``` neither

Comment: Have you tried `const session = require('electron').session` ?

Comment: @MatteoVioletto As I see from the documentation you first create `win = new BrowserWindow()` and after `win.webContents.session` you could try this way. In short hand `new BrowserWindow().webContents.session.cookies`